# Get Last 5 Sequential Numbers from Perl Text and 3 Preceding Characters

Tags: string, perl

How can someone get the last 5 sequential numbers from a Perl string and then additionally get the 3 characters that immediately proceed that sequence. For example, if the string is "This is just a bunch of ran 00000 Dom text. It has no 11111 meaning." Then I would want to get "11111" and then "no ".

Comment: What do you mean by "sequential numbers?"

Comment: You already got the nail on the head, but I meant numbers that have no spaces or characters in between... For example 82649 is a set of 5 sequential numbers... My example wasn't clear, so thank you for asking a clarifying question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = 'This is just a bunch of ran 00000 Dom text. It has no 11111 meaning.';

my ($pre, $digits) = $string =~ /.*(...)([0-9]{5})/;
say "<$pre>\t<$digits>";
```

- `[0-9]` matches any digit
- `{5}` means the previous thing should match five times
- `()` parentheses create a capture group
- `.` matches any character (excpet newline)
- `*` means the previous thing should match zero or more times, as much as possible. The `.*` therefore tries to match as much as possible from the string, to prevent matching the 00000.

Comment: You probably want `/s` in case the string contains newlines (and maybe `\A`, just to be explicit).